# which life cycle method i have to use for displaying updated content in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I developed one component (cart.vue) which is responsible for displaying cart items, cart is a child component of Dashboard.vue.Dashboard component contains one more component called DisplayBooks.vue .

DisplayBooks.vue contains one button ADD TO BAG when i click on that button the value should be changed to true in my database.what my Cart.vue displays whose cart value should be true upto this it's working fine i am using mounted() method for hitting API ,it's not updated my cart items (that means if i click on ADD TO BAG button that items is not displayed in my cart page ,if i want to see that means i have to refresh then it's working fine ).In order to refresh my page is there any other way to display the latest updated items also,Please help me to fix this thing..

`Cart.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="first-section">
        <div class="content">
            <h5>My Cart({{books.length}})</h5>
        </div>
        <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="container">

            <div class="mid-section">
                <img v-bind:src="book.file" alt="not found">
                <p class="title-section">{{book.name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="author-section">
                <p class="author-name">by {{book.author}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price-section">
                <h6>Rs.{{book.price}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                <input class="rectangle" value=1>
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-grps">
            <button class="btn" v-on:click="flip()" v-if="hide==true" type="submit">Place Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second -section">
        <div class="details-box">
            <input type="text" v-if="hide==true" class="initial-btn" placeholder="Customer Details" />
        </div>
        <div v-if="hide==false" class="fill-details">
            <form @submit.prevent="" class="address">
                <h4 class="heading">Customer Details</h4>
                <div class="name">
                    <input type="name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,10}" v-model="name">
                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="name">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="phoneNumber">
                    <label class="label">Phone Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="pin">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="pincode">
                    <label class="label">PinCode</label>
                </div>
                <div class="pin">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="locality">
                    <label class="label">Locality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="address-block">
                    <input class="address" type="text" required v-model="address">
                    <label id="Add" class="label">Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="city-landMark">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="city">
                    <label class="label">City/Town</label>
                </div>
                <div class="city-landMark">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="landmark">
                    <label class="label">LandMark</label>
                </div>
                <div class="Radio-Buttons">
                    <p>Type</p>
                    <div class="radio-btns flex-container">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" id="Home" value="Home" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="first-radio"> <label class="home" for="Home">Home</label></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input class="work-round" type="radio" id="Work" value="Work" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="second-radio"> <label for="Work" class="work-label">Work</label></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input class="other-round" type="radio" id="Other" value="Other" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="third-radio"><label for="Other">Other</label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-continue">
                        <button type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();" class="continue">continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    mounted() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("reloaded")) {
            localStorage.removeItem("reloaded");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("reloaded", "1");
            location.reload();
        }
        service.userDisplayCart().then(response => {
            this.books = response.data;
        })
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            hide: true,
            booksCount: 0,
            name: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            pincode: '',
            locality: '',
            city: '',
            address: '',
            landmark: '',
            type: '',
            books: []
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is in `DisplayBooks.vue`, but you've only shown `Cart.vue`.

Comment: @tony19, in DisplayBooks.vue i am using created() method ..

Comment: I'm assuming `DisplayBooks.vue` adds a book to the cart, and you're expecting `Cart.vue` to show the newly added book. That would require data communication between the two components (e.g., data binding in a common parent component, an event bus, a shared `Vue.observable`, or Vuex).

Comment: You use used updated() hook for displaying updated content

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be calling api after checking the reload value of localstorage in Cart.vue's mounted().
Cart.vue's mounted() does not run again when the button is pressed in DisplayBook.vue.

If I were you, I would try the method below.

To add an API call function to Cart.vue, and to execute Cart.vue's API call function when a button is pressed in DisplayBook.vue.

Or

Using Vuex to manage the condition. Vuex Store is reactive, so if DisplayBook.vue calls api and mutates the Store, it will also apply to Cart.vue.